# Do Android services block?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a class in my android application that I have registered as a service and a broadcast receiver in the manifest. The class begins when it receives the "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" intent from the system.

My question is: If I have the class wait for a socket connection:

```
class Test extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Serversocket server = new Serversocket();
    Socket s = server.accept();
}
```

Will this code block all other code execution of the app?

Comment: More likely it'll crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will block main thread. You can observe a freeze when this part of code will run. Better to call it in background using thread or async task

Comment: Thank you apk, that was my suspicion. Upon a quick google search, it seems extending the IntentService class is the way to go. If I implement the onHandleIntent() method, will it be able to catch the broadcasted "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" intent sent by the system?

Comment: @user3369427: "Upon a quick google search, it seems extending the IntentService class is the way to go" -- not for listening on a `ServerSocket`.  "will it be able to catch the broadcasted "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" intent sent by the system?" -- no, because `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is a broadcast. You are welcome to have your existing `BroadcastReceiver` start a service.

Comment: `IntentService`s run one after another in a queue. The socket will probably run indefinitely so you'll want to extend plain `Service` and start a new `Thread` in it for the socket.